# class template partial specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class template

```
class Class1;

template <class L, template<class> class F>
class N : public Class1, public F<L>
{ .... }
```

Now I want to partially specialize it in the following way:

```
template <class L>
class S;

template <class L>
class N<L, S<L> > : public Class1
{ .... }
```

But I get the following error in GCC:

```
type/value mismatch
```

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
class N<L, S<L> > : public Class1
```

`S<L>` is not a template. Change it to just `S` and it will compile.

Answer (score 2):

You passed in a class, not a template as the second parameter of your `N` specialization. I made a few changes so it compiles (primarily removing `<L>` from the specialization):

```
class Class1 {};

template <class L, template<class> class F>
class N : public Class1, public F<L>
{  };

template <class L>
class S;

template <class L>
class N<L, S > : public Class1
{  };
```

Answer (score 1):

gcc 4.8.1 outputs

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class L, template<class> class F> class N’
 class N<L, S<L> > : public Class1
                 ^
test.cpp:14:17: error:   expected a class template, got ‘S<L>’
```

Do not specialize S explicitly, just do :

```
template <class L>
class N<L, S> : public Class1 { };
```

Working example :

```
class Class1 {};

template <class L, template<class> class F>
class N : public Class1, public F<L> { };

template <class L>
class S;

template <class L>
class N<L, S> : public Class1 { };

int main () {}
```

---

**EDIT**: My guess is that you probably want to be able to write something like

```
int main ()
{
    N<int> n;
}
```

But with the code above this won't compile :

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
  N<int> n;
       ^
error: provided for ‘template<class L, template<class> class F> class N’
 class N : public Class1, public F<L>
       ^
error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
  N<int> n;
```

You should probably forget about the specialization and use a default template argument :

```
template <class L, template<class> class F = S>
class N : public Class1, public F<L> { };
```

Working example :

```
class Class1 {};

template <class L>
class S {};

template <class L, template<class> class F = S>
class N : public Class1, public F<L> {};

int main ()
{
    N<int> n;
}
```